# Why all subscribers are not called in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This is my code

```
let x = Rx.Observable.create(obs => window.obs = obs);
y = x.map(x=>x+2);
x.subscribe(v=>console.log("x got ",v));
y.subscribe(v=>console.log("y got ",v));
obs.next(1);
```

Output is

```
y got 3
```

I was expecting output to be

```
x got 1
y got 3
```

What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `window.obs` upon the second subscription.

If your usecase requires you to procedurally invoke emissions then you can use a Subject instead of creating an observable yourself:

```js
const subj = new Rx.Subject();
const sub1 = subj.subscribe(x => console.log('x got: ' + x));
const sub2 = subj.map(v => v * 2).subscribe(y => console.log('y got: ' + y));
subj.next(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.1.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it will be only one obs, and stream will flow through. what will be correct way of achieving same I want to?